# Present view shows black screen, why?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I'm making an app that, if a specific date has passed, presents a view controller after having started the app. The thing is: it just returns a black screen.
I've tested it setting the presented view controller as initial view controller and it worked perfectly; no black screen. Thus, my mistake has to be in the code.

I'm calling this function in `viewDidAppear()`:

```
if date.hasPassed {
        presentView(fromDate: date)
    }
```

This is not the actual code, it's more like a simplified version. Date is in my case a custom object from an array. The object saves it's properties to UserDefaults so that they can be presented in the appearing view controller. My `presentView(fromDate: date)` function is the following:

```
func presentView(fromDate: date) {
    let vc = NewViewController()

    let title = date.title ?? "My date"
    let description = date.description ?? "My description"

    UserDefaults.standard.set(title, forKey: "title")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(description, forKey: "description")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

But when actually calling this function it presents a black screen without showing any error. Can you tell me why?

Comment: What's in NewViewController? It might just be an empty black screen.

Comment: It's just a normal view controller with some labels... Don't think that that's the problem...

Comment: is this code executed from your startup viewcontroller ? Have you tried to delay the execution ?

Comment: yeah... didn't work either :(

Comment: Since your NewViewController is a custom class. If it's in storyboard you can change the background color in Attribute inspector. Or in viewDidLoad of you custom class do view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green. Or from your code above after this line 'let vc = NewViewController()' add vc.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

Answer (score 5):

If you created your NewViewController in storyboard, instantiating like that will not get the ui interface from there.

You can try to assign a StoryBoardId to it on storyboard and try:

```
func presentView(fromDate: date) {
   let newViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewControllerIdentifier")

   // your code

  self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

if the controller is in the same storyboard of your presenting controller. Or you can create a segue to it, call the segue and set you new controller data in "prepareForSegue".

Comment: This one worked for me thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try to add newviewcontroller by grabbing storyboard reference. and using instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier function.

Comment: also didn't work... maybe you can't call this function in viewDidAppear()? What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue where try i'm trying to present the View Controller on button pressed. Initially i was trying with following :-

```
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let vc = PaperViewController()
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

In order to resolve this error i added the storyboard Id which is "paper" in my case and used the instantiateViewController which worked for me.

```
   @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
     "paper") {
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it `XIB` case Double check that `VC` and `XIB` have the same name:

Incorrect:

```
DebugLogsVC.swift
DebugLogs.xib
```

Correct:

```
DebugLogsVC.swift
DebugLogsVC.xib
```

Present:

```
let vc = DebugLogsVC()
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, with a .xib file, the problem was that the target membership of the .xib file's owner wasn't set.

To see if it applies in your case, check the "Target Membership" section of the File Inspector.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This happens a lot to me too in my case I was using a variety of `viewControllers`, i.e. `UIAlertController`, a `Custom nib UIViewController`, a `Storyboard UIViewController`, and a `Hard Coded UIViewController`. I'm not sure if this is a bug on `Apple` but to fix this problem I presented the `viewController` on the `viewDidAppear` after a time delay.

Here's my code.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // 1 second delay so the views will render first before presenting the alert
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.presentTheAlert), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

func presentTheAlert() {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

So essentially what this does is that, it waits for the view to be fully rendered before presenting another `viewController`.

Answer (score -1):

I like to put the presentation of the view controller in a method like you did and use

```
- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay;
```

to show it in viewDidAppear. However, I have found I've had to play with the delay value since in the simulator it works with 0.2, but on a device it might not. It's really annoying that Apple can't provide developers with an event that is safe for showing new views.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -2):

try the following:

```
let bundle = Bundle.main
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: bundle)
var newViewController: UIViewController!
newViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewControllerIdentifier")
present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This answer could be improved with a little explanation of why this is worth trying.